# Company logo partially visible. What could be wrong?

Tags: image, rendering

I was asked this question recently in an interview:

1. Company logo appears partially on
   the new build of browser
2. Eliminated Server down problem, not network issue
3. Company Logo which is a JPG : maybe the image rendering broken
4. What else could be wrong?

I could not think of anything else. Please help. Can someone elaborate?

Thanks.

Comment: Could a dead link on page making the rest of the page not load properly?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the browser software is not correctly dealing with objects that are split into multiple packets - acquiring the first packet(s) of a progressively loaded image and not the remaining ones could result in a partially displayed image.

Comment: Isn't that image rendering component?

Answer (score 0):

The new build of the browser most probably changed their css rendering engine, adhered to new standards, etc.

What looks right in the old browser might not look right in the new browser simply because the rendering is changed.  This is especially true with IE6 to IE7 and IE7 to IE8.